# PHP How to compute between members of 2 arrays and return the id of the member that returns true?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a function and 2 arrays such that:

```
    function subtract($x, $y){
     return $y-$x;
    }
    $a1=array(array("first", 5), array("second", 6), array("third", 4));
    $a2=array(3);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($a1 as $index=>$value){
    $result=array(subtract($value[$i], $a2[0]));
if($result=1){
//return third in this case}
    }
```

In the foreach loop I would like to return third in this case once the function returns true. How do I do that?

Comment: Your function doesn't **return** anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use your same structure, but don't think is the best approach.

```
    function subtract($x, $y)
    {
        return $x-$y;
    }

$a1=array(array("first", 5), array("second", 6), array("third", 4));
$a2=array(3);

foreach ($a1 as $value)
    {
    $result=subtract($value[1], $a2[0]);
        if($result==1)
        {
            echo $value[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I accepted your answer, your response is appreciated. But I would like to store all the possible results, ie 2,3,1 in an array. Then if one of them(4), then I would like to echo "third". That was my original problem, but I didn't failed to explain it :(